# No gain in CMOS differential amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, cmos, differential

Currently I'm working on the design of 1st stage of CMOS differential amp (pic. 1). I'm using classical design to achieve at least some gain. I'm using CMOS 90nm process and SPECTRE simulator.
[image: schematic]

So far output for typical simulation is something like this (Output of simulation. Red = IN, cyrene = out.):

[image: Output of simulation. Red = IN, cerulean = out.]

Also outputs are color coded on schematic

This schematic should work even with input common mode equals zero, so in simulation `vin_common = 0` and vinp is grounded.
Typical RS = 200K, but I tried numbers from 1K to 300K

I tried to change W/L of transistors, and so far they seem picked reasonably, but there is still **no gain** in case of any W/L ratios. What's wrong with the design, or with it's W/L ratios?

P.S. As you asked here is some characteristics of MOSFETS:

[image: Scheme]
[image: Curves]

[image: Sc]
[image: Vds]

Comment: Do you have sm. sig parameters at the DC op point (esp. id, gm and rout for each FET)? If so, can you enable that annotation and take a new screenshot showing those?

Comment: @nanofarad Thanks for response, I added MOSFET characteristics in my question.

Comment: Rather than the transfer curves for individual FETs, can you show the actual small-signal parameters for the FETs as they are in the full amplifier circuit? Depending on your PDK this option might look different, but on tsmc18 it would be found by right-clicking the schematic canvas, selecting annotate, and dc op point. The idea is to verify that all FETs have expected drain currents, mode of operation, etc *in-circuit*. With the plots you have given so far, I'd need to perform manual solving techniques to infer the state of any individual FET at the op point.

Comment: @nanofarad , I'll try to use this feature if I find it. For not I haven't  heard of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your transistor symbols are not placed in a matched manner.

Make them identical, both in the top PChannel? diffpair

and

in the bottom Nchannel? current mirror.

===============================================

Also, without I_V plots of the transistors (sweep the Vds 0 to 3 volts; step the gate with 0.1 volt steps from 0v to 1.5v; do for Vbulk_source = 0v, for 1v or 2v) you are only guessing about the FET behaviors.

Also, longer channel devices may be required.

Comment: I added I_V plots. But matching symbols is not so reasonable, because in fact they are 100% symmetrical on symbol and layout level.